# How to fix ‘ No such file or directory’ error in execute console-script by setup.py?

Tags: django, python-3.x, setup.py

I wrote a static blog generator built using Django. Some problems occurred when I packaged it with setup.py and created the corresponding executable.

When I use `pip install maltose` to install it and run `maltose-cli migrate`, everything is normal so far.

But when I run `maltose-cli runserver`, I get a error that `c:\software\python\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Software\Python\Scripts\maltose-cli': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

And then, I try `maltose-cli.py runserver`, everything is OK.

This is my `setup.py`

```py
setup(
    name=NAME,
    version=about['__version__'],
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    author=AUTHOR,
    author_email=EMAIL,
    python_requires=REQUIRES_PYTHON,
    url=URL,
    packages=find_packages(include=["maltose", 'maltose.*']),

    scripts=['maltose-cli.py'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['maltose-cli=maltose:execute'],
    },
    install_requires=REQUIRED,
    extras_require=EXTRAS,
    include_package_data=True,
    license='MIT',
    classifiers=[
        # Trove classifiers
        # Full list: https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
    ],
    # $ setup.py publish support.
    cmdclass={
        'upload': UploadCommand,
    },
)
```

Dir

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        2019/4/20     18:41                maltose
-a----        2019/4/20     18:47             90 maltose-cli.py
-a----        2019/4/20     18:47           4047 setup.py
```

In `maltose/__init__.py`

```py
import os
import sys


def execute():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_DEBUG', 'True')
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'maltose.maltose.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line()
```

If you need, all the code is at https://github.com/MaltoseEditor/maltose

How can I solve it? I hope that it will work fine when I run `maltose-cli runserver`.

Answer (score -1):

This error is related with the auto-reload functionality when the project's source code changes.

As a workaround, use the [--noreload flag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-runserver-noreload) to disable this feature.

```
maltose-cli runserver --noreload
```

Side note: this also applies to Bottle.py